# How to show context menu in UICollectionView via single tap?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, I have no issue in showing context menu in `UICollectionView`, via long press.

```
extension BackupViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {        
    // Long press, to show context menu.
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        configureContextMenu(index: indexPath.row)
    }
 
    func configureContextMenu(index: Int) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration{
        let context = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { (action) -> UIMenu? in
            
            let edit = UIAction(title: "Edit", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.pencil"), identifier: nil, discoverabilityTitle: nil, state: .off) { (_) in
                print("edit button clicked")
                //add tasks...
            }
            let delete = UIAction(title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), identifier: nil, discoverabilityTitle: nil,attributes: .destructive, state: .off) { (_) in
                print("delete button clicked")
                //add tasks...
            }
            return UIMenu(title: "Options", image: nil, identifier: nil, options: UIMenu.Options.displayInline, children: [edit,delete])
        }
        return context
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // TODO: How to show the same long press context menu, via single tap?
    }
}
```

---

Now, I would like to show the context menu, when user performs single tap on the cell.

May I know, how can I achieve so?

If that is not something possible/ straightforward, is there any workaround to achieve so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the context menu with single tap on cell. But you have to add UIButton in your cell and present the context menu with this button.

```
final class YourCustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    private let menuButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    
    override class func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(menuButton)
        configureButtonConstraints()
        configureMenu()
    }
    
    private func configureButtonConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            menuButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            menuButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            menuButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            menuButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    private func configureMenu() {
        let editAction = UIAction(title: "Edit") { _ in
            print("Edit Button Clicked")
        }
        
        let deleteAction = UIAction(title: "Delete") { _ in
            print("Delete Button Clicked")
        }
        
        let menuForCell = UIMenu(title: "Options", options: UIMenu.Options.displayInline, children: [editAction, deleteAction])
        menuButton.menu = menuForCell
    }
}
```

If you use UIButton like this, you will be show context menu when single tap on cell. But this usage available with iOS 14+.